# Pandas to_sql - append vs replace

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand how to modify the to_sql function to my needs. Here's the dataframe `df_interface`:

```
| YEAR | QUARTER | USER_ACCOUNT | BYTES         | USER_CODE |
|------|---------|--------------|---------------|-----------|
| 2020 | 2       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 2       | Exel2        | 441712306685  | 348995    |
```

I'm trying to insert this into a table `USER_USAGE` (via oracle+cx and SQLAlchemy). The contents of this table before the insert are:

```
| YEAR | QUARTER | USER_ACCOUNT | BYTES         | USER_CODE |
|------|---------|--------------|---------------|-----------|
| 2020 | 1       | SHtte34      | 34560         | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 1       | Exel2        | 5478290       | 348995    |
```

I would like a new row inserted only in the case of a new quarter AND account. Basically I would like this after the insert:

```
| YEAR | QUARTER | USER_ACCOUNT | BYTES         | USER_CODE |
|------|---------|--------------|---------------|-----------|
| 2020 | 1       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 1       | Exel2        | 5478290       | 348995    |
| 2020 | 2       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 2       | Exel2        | 441712306685  | 348995    |
```

Here's the code with "replace":

```
conn = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://{}:{}@{}/?service_name={}'.format(s_uid,s_pwd,s_db,s_service))

df_interface.to_sql('USER_USAGE', conn, if_exists='replace',dtype={'USER_ACCOUNT': types.String(df_interface.USER_ACCOUNT.str.len().max()),'USER_CODE': types.String(df_interface.USER_CODE.str.len().max())},index=False)
```

This seems to be removing the previous quarter(1) values as well. Output after replace:

```
 | YEAR | QUARTER | USER_ACCOUNT | BYTES         | USER_CODE |
|------|---------|--------------|---------------|-----------|
| 2020 | 2       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 2       | Exel2        | 441712306685  | 348995    |
```

Append is closer to what I want to see, however if I accidentally run the program twice, I'm seeing duplicated rows:

```
| YEAR | QUARTER | USER_ACCOUNT | BYTES         | USER_CODE |
|------|---------|--------------|---------------|-----------|
| 2020 | 1       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 1       | Exel2        | 5478290       | 348995    |
| 2020 | 2       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 2       | Exel2        | 441712306685  | 348995    |
| 2020 | 1       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 1       | Exel2        | 5478290       | 348995    |
| 2020 | 2       | SHtte34      | 7392577516389 | 2320885   |
| 2020 | 2       | Exel2        | 441712306685  | 348995    |
```

How do I use the "append" but also prevent duplicates from getting created in case of an inadvertent run?

Answer (score 2):

The `if_exists` argument refers to the table as a whole, not individual rows within the table. `if_exists="replace"` means "if the table exists then drop it and create a new one with the rows in the DataFrame, whereas `if_exists="append"` means "append the DataFrame rows to the existing table".

If potentially you only want to insert some (or none) of the rows into an existing table then you can't use `to_sql` to insert them directly. Instead, you could:

• Create a temporary table (e.g., `USER_USAGE_TEMP`) with the same structure as the main `USER_USAGE` table.

• Use `to_sql` to upload the DataFrame to the temp table (with `if_exists="append"`).

• Execute an INSERT statement like

```sql
INSERT INTO USER_USAGE (YEAR, QUARTER, USER_ACCOUNT, BYTES, USER_CODE)
SELECT YEAR, QUARTER, USER_ACCOUNT, BYTES, USER_CODE FROM USER_USAGE_TEMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM USER_USAGE UU
    WHERE UU.YEAR = USER_USAGE_TEMP.YEAR AND UU.QUARTER = USER_USAGE_TEMP.QUARTER
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. What are other ways to only insert some rows (per the above requirement) using SQLAlchemy/Oracle+cx?

Comment: You could use an approach [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39551237/2144390) except use an `INSERT … WHERE NOT EXISTS …` instead of an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @Shallunsard If you **really** need to use to_sql(), you can use a table that has trigger that does the insert for you in another table. Don't expect this to be easy, fast, or portable; but if you *ever* need a hack like this I guess it's the only option.

Comment: I'm open to options that don't need to_sql, really just looking for the most pain-free solution within the SQLAlchemy/Oraclecx/PyODBC modules.